# Unicode argument expected PYQRCODE

Tags: python-2.7, svg, unicode

With the following, that should generate an in memory image:

```
url = pyqrcode.create(user.get_totp_uri())
stream = StringIO()
url.svg(stream, scale=3)
return stream.getvalue().encode('utf-8'), 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Expires': '0'}
```

I get the following error:

```
File "E:\Data\pathsdb\flask\lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\builder.py", line 1118, in _svg
write_bytes(b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

With the following code:

```
url = pyqrcode.create(user.get_totp_uri())
stream = BytesIO()
url.svg(stream, scale=3)
return stream.getvalue(), 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Expires': '0'}
```

One should use BytesIO and drop encoding.